# How to use perl to modify YAML file values using YAML::Tiny or other?

Tags: perl, parsing, yaml

Morning, I am looking for how to modify some values in the yaml that are pretty deep down (i.e., memory and cpu related).

```
 ---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sentry-agent
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 30
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 240
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 0%
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sentry-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sentry-agent-usr
      serviceAccount: sentry-agent-usr
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - sentry-agent
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: sentry-agent
        image: <image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: sentry-agent
          - secretRef:
              name: sentry-creds
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1000m"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
             port: 8080
            path: /healthz
```

Morning, I am trying to figure out how to modify the memory and cpu values using perl's YAML::Tiny module.

The examples do not get very far with depth.  I see they have

```
use YAML::Tiny;

# Open the config
my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->read( 'file.yml' );

# Get a reference to the first document
my $config = $yaml->[0];
```

This is pretty standard.  I tried something like:

```
print "$config->{spec}->{template}->{containers}->{resources}->{memory}\n";
```

This does not work.  Any expert know what is wrong with the path I did?

Comment: Try `$config->{spec}{template}{spec}{containers}[0]{resources}{requests}{memory}`. It gives output `512Mi` here

Comment: `YAML::Tiny` can't parse that sample yaml file you provided.

Answer (score 3):

First and last line of the YAML are indented wrong. After fixing that, you can access the value `1Gi` via:

```
print "$config->{spec}{template}{spec}{containers}[0]{resources}{limits}{memory}\n";
```

Hint: use a dumper module to visualise complex nested data.

Comment: Thank you!  The {container}[0] was big in getting me to my destination.  I will try a Dumper as well as suggested.